# Search (Keyword Query) returning different number of results depending on ordering rule

Tags: search

We have a situation (SharePoint Server 2013 Search) where we have implemented a search results page using the API. We are building a KeywordQuery object and setting the QueryText.

We are setting the sort order as follows:

```
kq.SortList.Add("Title", Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SortDirection.Ascending);
```

Does anybody know why the following would occur? We get different numbers of results based on the ordering direction and type. All are run with exactly the same query:

```
Ordered by relevance rank (default): 249 results
Ordered by Title ascending: 250 results
Ordered by Title descending: 250 results
Ordered by Created ascending: 249 results
Ordered by Created descending: 250 results
```

We are counting the Rows.Count method applied to the DataTable generated by the SearchExecutor as follows:

```
SearchExecutor searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor();

ResultTableCollection resultTableCollection = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(kq);

IEnumerable<ResultTable> resultTables = resultTableCollection.Filter("TableType", KnownTableTypes.RelevantResults);
var resultTable = resultTables.FirstOrDefault();
resultDataTable = resultTable.Table;

int totalResults = resultDataTable.Rows.Count;
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.